# Actix: what's the right way to move shared data into multiple threads?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have a `config` Struct that I'm sharing across my actix app like so:

```
pub fn run(addr: &str, pg_pool: PgPool, config: Settings) -> Result<Server, std::io::Error> {
    let pool = web::Data::new(pg_pool); 
    let arc_config = web::Data::new(Arc::new(config)); // <---

    let server = HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .service(exhaust)
            .app_data(pool.clone())
            .app_data(arc_config.clone()) // <---
    })
    .bind(addr)?
    .run();
```

I then have a handler that is trying to spawn multiple threads and pass that `config` struct into each:

```
#[get("/exhaust")]
pub async fn exhaust(pool: web::Data<PgPool>, config: web::Data<Arc<Settings>>) -> impl Responder {
    for _ in 1..16 {
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let inner_config = Arc::clone(&config);
            get_single_tweet(inner_config.as_ref().deref(), "1401287393228038149");
        });
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok()
}
```

My thinking was that because `config` is already wrapped in an `Arc()` I should be able to just `Arc::clone()` it inside of each thread and then deref into the underlying variable.

But I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `config`
  --> src/twitter/routes/pull.rs:63:36
   |
58 | pub async fn exhaust(pool: web::Data<PgPool>, config: web::Data<Arc<Settings>>) -> impl Responder {
   |                                               ------ move occurs because `config` has type `actix_web::web::Data<Arc<Settings>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
63 |         let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                    ^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
64 |             let inner_config = Arc::clone(&config);
   |                                            ------ use occurs due to use in closure
```

I'm struggling to understand why this fails. If the config is inside an `Arc`, then why does the compiler think I'm trying to move it instead of incrementing the reference count?

I've also tried a number of other approaches, all unsuccessful:

- Removing the `move` in front of the closure - compiler complains the borrowed value doesn't live long enough
- Dereferencing `config` and wrapping it in a fresh `Arc()` - similar error as original

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clone it *before* it's moved. Otherwise your first iteration will necessarily need to take it (since there is no guarantee `config` will still exist to be cloned when the task runs). Then you get the error you see for the second iteration, since it too necessarily needs to move `config`; that's what it means by "value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop".

```rust
#[get("/exhaust")]
pub async fn exhaust(pool: web::Data<PgPool>, config: web::Data<Arc<Settings>>) -> impl Responder {
    for _ in 1..16 {
        let handle = thread::spawn({
            // Clone this here, so the closure gets its very own to move-capture.
            let inner_config = config.get_ref().clone();
            move || {
                get_single_tweet(inner_config.as_ref().deref(), "1401287393228038149");
            });
        }
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok()
}
```

Note that `web::Data` itself is already [just a wrapper around `Arc`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/src/actix_web/data.rs.html#65), so you have some redundancy with the nested `Arc`. You may just want:

```rust
#[get("/exhaust")]
pub async fn exhaust(pool: web::Data<PgPool>, config: web::Data<Settings>) -> impl Responder {
    for _ in 1..16 {
        let handle = thread::spawn({
            let inner_config = config.clone();
            move || {
                get_single_tweet(inner_config.as_ref().deref(), "1401287393228038149");
            });
        }
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok()
}
```

Comment: wow so obvious in hindsight... thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid cloning you could create a static variable that can be updated at runtime to avoid cloning on every request.

```rust
use tokio::sync::OnceCell;

//GLOBAL
static CLIENT: OnceCell<Pool<MySql>> = OnceCell::const_new();

//In function
if let None = CLIENT.get() {
   let _ = CLIENT.set(pool);
}

//returns a reference
CLIENT.get()
```